# Generating different Captcha

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, captcha

In my website, I used simple captcha generator and I successfully generated random captcha whenever the signup page is reloaded. But when I tried to dynamically refresh the captcha (in the case it wasn't clear) without reloading all the page the captcha image still the same, and I don't understand why this happens.

the php code:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$c = new Captcha;
$c->CCaptcha();
imagepng($c->image);
imagedestroy($c->image);
```

And note that the Captcha is php class that generates the captcha.

my html/js code looks like:

```js
function cap()
{
 
 document.getElementById("cimg").src = "captcha.php";
}
```

```html
<img src="captcha.php?n=0" id="cimg" name = "cimg"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="cap()" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh </button>
    <span class = "col-sm-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="cap()" id="ceap" placeholder="Write the word in the image"></span>
```

So what is the problem, and why the image still the same unless I reload all the page?

Comment: at a guess caching. i would recommend https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html rather than rolling your own

Comment: [*Rolling your own, huh?*...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUWD-FflZPI) @Dagon

Comment: Browser caching? Try adding a time-based parameter to the url, like `captcha.php?1469660810` (this one is UNIX timestamp for exampe)

Comment: @yuriy636 your solution worked, but only once (it refresh only one time, then it stop!)!

Comment: @Dagon Yes I know about google's service. But I've already finished the "hard" work (The captcha class) :)

Comment: @ParcRoi are you generating a different timestamp for every refresh? I mean the `cap()` function gets the current time and applies it to the url.

Comment: @yuriy636 Ok your solution worked by simple trick: in javascript i added the folowing: 
document.getElementById("cimg").src = "captcha.php?"+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1). It worked fine, but I am not sure if this an good way. Anyway it is working fine thank you so much and for Dagon :)